# How to send keyed message to Kafka using Spring Cloud Stream Supplier

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to use Spring Cloud Stream to produce keyed (message with specific key) messages to Kafka.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudStreamKafkaApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudStreamKafkaApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  Supplier<DataRecord> process(){
    return () -> new DataRecord(42L);
  }

}
```

What do I need to change in the Supplier code to provide key? 
Is it possible in new style of API (using lambdas)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a `Message<?>` and set the `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` header:

```
@Bean
Supplier<Message<String>> process() {
    return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "bar".getBytes())
            .build();
}
```

(assumes the default key serializer (byte[]).

**EDIT**

This will be called endlessly.

If you want to send a finite stream, I believe you have to switch to the reactive model.

```
@Bean
Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> processFinite() {
    Message<String> msg1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "bar".getBytes())
            .build();
    Message<String> msg2 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("baz")
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "qux".getBytes())
            .build();
    return () -> {
        return Flux.just(msg1, msg2);
    };
}
```

There is also `Flux.fromStream(myStream)`.

Which will end at the end of the stream.

**EDIT2**

You can also use the `StreamBridge`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Comment: Gary, thank you for your response. I was able to transition from phase «it doesn't work» to phase «it doesn't stop working» :) Is there a way to create kinda one-off supplier (think about loader that generates data during startup and exists). How I can do that?

Comment: Hi Viktor, I am not an expert in the reactive space but, according to [the docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources), it looks like you have to switch to the reactive model for that; see the edit to my answer.